# Can using UndecidableInstances pragma locally have global consequences on compilation termination?

Tags: haskell, compilation, ghc, language-extension

Suppose a Haskell library designer decides to use [`UndecidableInstances`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.2/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#undecidable-instances) for some reason. The library compiles fine. Now suppose some program uses the library (like defines some instances of its type classes), but doesn't use the extension. Can it happen that the compilation fails (doesn't terminate)?

If such a scenario can happen, I'd be happy to see an example. For example, as [*mtl*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) uses `UndecidableInstances` a lot, is it possible to write a program that depends on *mtl* (or any other standard library that uses the extension), doesn't use `UndecidableInstances` itself, but fails to compile because of undecidability?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Great question!

In general this is certainly possible. Consider this module:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, UndecidableInstances #-}

module M where

class C a b | a -> b where
  f :: a -> b

instance C a b => C [a] [b]
  where f = map f
```

It compiles by itself just fine. However, if you import this module and define

```
g x = x + f [x]
```

you'll get

```
Context reduction stack overflow; size = 201
Use -fcontext-stack=N to increase stack size to N
  C [b] b
In the second argument of `(+)', namely `f [x]'
In the expression: x + f [x]
In an equation for `g': g x = x + f [x]
```

---

Regarding the mtl instances, I don't see how something like this is possible, but I also don't have a proof that it's not.

Comment: I was playing with your solution and I managed to cut it down to `class C a where f :: a -> a` and `instance C [[a]] => C [a] where f = id`, which doesn't need any other extension but `UndecidableInstances`.

Comment: After examining it `mtl`, I believe it's not possible to cause the compiler to loop by using it. The only reason it needs the extension is because some of its instances fail the [Coverage Condition](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-rules). But the idea behind the condition is satisfied - all rhs type variables can be inferred from `mtl`'s instance declarations.

Comment: Huh, I'm surprised `C [[a]]` doesn't require `FlexibleContexts`.

Comment: It does, but it seems that `UndecidableInstances` implies `FlexibleContexts`.